# PostgreSQL update from subquery

Tags: postgresql

I have a following PostgreSQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id INTEGER DEFAULT nextval('users_user_id_seq') NOT NULL,
    user_old_id CHARACTER VARYING(36),
    created_by INTEGER,
    created_by_old character varying(36),
    last_updated_by INTEGER,
    last_updated_by_old character varying(36),
    CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);
```

Based on data in this table I need to update:

1. `created_by` field with `user_id` from this table for every row
   where `created_by_old = user_old_id` Please note that `created_by_old` can be NULL and therefore must be avoided in this case.
2. `last_updated_by` field with `user_id` from this table for every
   row where `last_updated_by_old = user_old_id` Please note that `last_updated_by_old` can be NULL and therefore must be avoided in this case.

This is a sample data:

**Actual:**

```
user_id | user_old_id | created_by | created_by_old | last_updated_by | last_updated_by_old 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       | aaa         |            | ccc            |                 | bbb
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2       | bbb         |            | ddd            |                 | aaa
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3       | ccc         |            |                |                 | ddd
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4       | ddd         |            | aaa            |                 |
```

**Expected:**

```
user_id | user_old_id | created_by | created_by_old | last_updated_by | last_updated_by_old 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       | aaa         |  3         | ccc            |   2             | bbb
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2       | bbb         |  4         | ddd            |   1             | aaa
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3       | ccc         |            |                |   4             | ddd
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4       | ddd         |  1         | aaa            |                 |
```

I think it can be implemented with a subquery but can't figure out by myself right now how to implement this query. Please help.

Comment: Please provide data sample and expected output.

Comment: What did you try until now ?

Comment: @sagi I have updated my question with a sample data and expected result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not too efficient ,but if that's not an issue you can do this :

```
UPDATE users u
SET u.created_by = (SELECT t.user_id FROM users t
                    WHERE u.created_by_old = t.user_old_id),
    u.last_updated_by = (SELECT s.user_id FROM users s
                         WHERE u.last_updated_by = s.user_old_id)
```

Comment: Thanks. Please note that `created_by_old` or `last_updated_by_old`  in some rows can be empty and therefore update of appropriate field must be avoided in this case. How to update this query in order to support this case ?

Comment: Why? If it's `NULL` then the result will be `NULL` as well . @alexanoid

Comment: Thanks. Also I tried this query `UPDATE users u SET u.created_by = (SELECT t.user_id FROM users t WHERE u.created_by_old = t.user_old_id), u.last_updated_by = (SELECT s.user_id FROM users s WHERE u.last_updated_by_old = s.user_old_id)` but it fails with a following error: `ERROR:  column "u" of relation "users" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE users u SET u.created_by = (SELECT t.user_id FROM use...`

Comment: I have updated u.created_by to simple created_by and now everything works fine! Thank you !

Answer (score 8):

If you want a more efficient update statement you can use a derived table that gets the information you want as the source of your update statement:

```
update users u1
  set created_by = t.new_created_by, 
      last_updated_by = t.new_updated_by
from ( 
  select u2.user_id, u2.user_old_id,
         cr.user_id as new_created_by, 
         lu.user_id as new_updated_by
  from users u2
    left join users cr on cr.user_old_id = u2.created_by_old
    left join users lu on lu.user_old_id = u2.last_updated_by_old
) t
where t.user_id = u1.user_id;
```

Usually the target table of the update should never be repeated in the `from` clause, but this case is a rare example where it can't be avoided.

But this will **only** work properly if `user_old_id` is also unique, not only `user_id`.

Online example: http://rextester.com/HKM21985